# Eclipse cannot shutdown BEA WebLogic server

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin

I am using `Eclipse Galileo` and I have the `BEA WebLogic Server v.10` installed.
The problem that I am facing is that the server cannot be stopped anymore(running in debug mode).
For example it shows the progress bar of stopping until 93% and after that it gives the message `"The server cannot be stopped within timeout."`; I can only restart eclipse in order to start again the server.

In the console I see the message:

```
"C:/bea1001/jrockit_150_11/bin/java -classpath C:/bea1001/wlserver_10.0/server/lib/weblogic.jar weblogic.Admin -url t3://localhost:80 -username weblogic -password 12345678 FORCESHUTDOWN AdminServer 
Server "AdminServer" was force shutdown successfully ..." -
```

But it seems that something is blocking to stop the server.

Can anyone tell me what I can do?

p.s. I tried to delete and create a new server in the eclipse but I still have the same problem

Thanks and regards,

Luisa

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem: I changed the port of the BEA WebLogic to be 80 and this port was used also by Skype.
I changed the port of the Skype and now the server stops

Luisa

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and another solution may be to start Eclipse with java command (in my case Weblogic was running as java.exe, but Eclipse as javaw.exe). Also check if the same version of JDK is used for running both Weblogic and Eclipse.